# Getting IFERROR to move to next row if I paste a value in the previous row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Not sure if the title sums up my problem enough. Basically, I am attempting to streamline my data entry by using formulas. How my data is set up is I have three tabs (Sheet 1, Sheet 2, and Sheet 3). Sheet 1 is filled with basic information (age, date, sex, etc.) and each line is a "Host" and indicated by Column 1 Host_Ind. In another column I have it to be either TRUE or FALSE for SHEET 3. What I am hoping for is that when I click "TRUE" it automatically populates SHEET 3. I have figured out the following code to do that:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Host!$A$2:$A$500,SMALL(IF(TRUE=Host!$T$2:T500,ROW(Host!$A$2:$A$500),""),ROW()-1)-1,1),"")
```

Which successfully moves the Host_Ind to Sheet 3. The problem I am running into is on sheet three I have to copy the Host_Ind code multiple rows to indicate some behavior. I do this by copying the Host_Ind_Code and pasting "values" into the next row. I've pasted a screenshot example below on how I want my data to look like.

How Sheet 3 should look
[image]

How Sheet 1 (or Host Info) looks like
[image]

How Sheet 3 actually comes out.
[image]

You can see that because I copied and pasted the values of Host_001, it completely skipped Host_002 and went to Host_003 even though all three hosts are "TRUE".
Unfortunately, when I do that, it seems to interrupt the formula above and will not populate the next row with Host_002. Depending on how many behaviors I have, it skips the following hosts. So for the above example, I have two more behaviors, which means it'll skip two hosts and the formula will start up with Host_004 and ignore Hosts_002 and Host_003. Is there a way to edit my code above to have the formula skip rows where the values are and start the next row? I can attach a link to an example of my datasheet.

I hope this explains clearly enough what I am hoping to do! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Formulas cannot move (automatically) by other means than by use of VBA (or other) macros.

Comment: @Hannu I see, do you know of any VBA's that might lead along these lines? I don't have an issue with VBAs, but I've never used them before

Comment: VBA = Visual Basic for Applications. Record a Macro or write code in a "Module" in the VBE (VB Editor) which opens if you hit Alt+F11.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @FlexYourData I am using Microsoft 365 for Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of that might be of interest.

**Option 1**

Use a formula to pre-build the number of instances of each host code. The issue with this is that because the formula is dynamic, it will be tricky to align with other data on sheet3 if you want to add rows later.

Instead of TRUE/FALSE for the Behavior flag, may I recommend you use a number that indicates how many rows you want to complete for that host?

You can then use this formula in cell A2 of Sheet3 and you won't need to copy and paste the host indicator when adding new behavior rows for that host.

```
=LET(
  b,FILTER(HSTACK(Sheet1!A2:A4,Sheet1!E2:E4),Sheet1!E2:E4>0),
  m,REPT(TAKE(b,,1),TAKE(b,,-1)),
  s,SUBSTITUTE(m,"H",",H"),
  tj,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,s),
  TEXTSPLIT(tj,,",",TRUE)
)
```

[image]

**Option 2**

Use data validation to populate the Host_Ind_Code on Sheet3. This will ensure that you can't enter a host that isn't supposed to be there.

First, enter this formula somewhere out of sight on sheet3. This will give you a list of the valid Host codes for sheet3 that can be used in data validation for column A of the table.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A4,Sheet1!E2:E4)
```

Adjust the ranges in this formula to fit the data on sheet1.

Now select any cell in the host code column of the table on sheet3, then go to the Data tab of the ribbon and use the Data Validation button:

[image]

Configure the dialog like this:

[image]

In the Source box, enter the cell address of where you put the formula above (in my example, it's in cell F1). The hashmark after the cell address means "all cells created by the formula in this cell". So, $F$1# returns the list of host codes in F1:F2:

[image]

After you click OK, you'll notice there's a drop down button in the host code column on sheet3. From this you can select a valid host code for the current row.

This drop-down will be available in the host code column when a new row is created providing you press Tab to get to the end of the current row then press Tab to create a new row:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response! So the only difficulty is that we don't have a determined number of behaviors. Some hosts might have 10 behaviors, some might only have three or two and we usually enter the data as we go through each Host rather than enter it at the end. For the second option, we sometimes have over 1,000 hosts we are entering data for, so I'm not sure if a drop-down is possible either. This function in excel might not exist it is seeming.

Comment: I believe the maximum number of items in data validation drop-down list is something like 32768, so I don't think it'll be an issue. However, if you're really trying to build a robust data entry tool on an M365 budget, then you might be better off using MS Access or similar low-code database and form design tool.